# Movement and Speech

Tags: semantics

This may be a little weird, but...
How can we describe words or phrases that have a *specific* accompanying movement?  What sort of topics do they cover?  To what degree has research been done on this? Are there examples in English?

I'm thinking of situations in which the meaning of the utterance would be fundamentally changed without the motion.  Obviously, this would apply only to spoken (not signed) languages.

Comment: Hello Adele, your question is basically asking for *any* example of such expressions, making this eligible to be closed as not constructive. Can you try narrowing it down? As long as you get to ask for a specific answer, any change you wish to apply is OK.

Comment: I will do my best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Some languages have whole systems of them. I've been told by a field worker in Guatemala that [Ixil](http://www.ethnologue.com/show_language.asp?code=ixl) has a whole gestural paradigm of numeral classifiers -- hand gestures that indicate whether you're counting animals, people, things of different kinds, undifferentiated "stuff", etc -- gestures that accompany the numeric counters, in speech, as they're used.

On the other hand, some languages don't even have numbers.

English does have at least one word, pronounced /ye/, usually spelled "yea" or "yay" when it has to be spelled, that functions only as a gestural quantifier, as in

- *The stick is about /ye/ long.*

where the speaker's hand motions and coordinated listeners' eye motions are expected to accompany stressed /e/. This is a gestural version of deixis.

In fact, this is part of Chuck Fillmore's example of a deictically unanchored sentence

- *Meet me here tomorrow at the same time, with a stick about yea long.*

This is a grammatical sentence, but if you found it on a note in a bottle in the middle of the Pacific Ocean it would be a little hard to understand properly.

> (Parenthetically, [***Deixis***](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/FillmoreDeixisLectures.pdf) is the general category for words, grammar, idioms, and other linguistic phenomena that depend on the particular spatial (*here, this*), temporal (*now, soon*), social or personal (*yours, mine*) parameters of one particular speech act.)

Comment: I don't know about Ixil but as for *ye*, I'm not really convinced. By the same token, you'd probably have to say *this* has to be accompanied by a gesture in a phrase *about this long*. Isn't it the same *ye* as in *ye olde pub*? I'd say it's just a specific use, not a general feature of the word.

Comment: It's not pronounced the same. _Ye_ is a misspelling of the word _the_, it's consciously archaic, like _thou_, and it's pronounced /yi/, not /ye/. Also, you asked for obligatory associations of lexical items with movements, and deictic elements may be but aren't required to be associated with gestures, or any other part of the communicational spectrum, like intonation, cocked eyebrows, ironic stress, or lip pursing.

Comment: @KamilS. There are circumstances where "a stick this long" might not co-occur with a gesture, e.g."Five meters is big; I don't think we'll find a stick this long". But jlawler is correct, I don't think "yea" can occur without a gestural deixis accompanying it.

Comment: i.e., "yea" doesn't mean "this" unless there is also a gesture.

Comment: Hm, I can find neither the usage nor the pronunciation you describe in a dictionary, but you're the native speakers so I won't argue. Anyway, my point was that it will not *always* be accompanied by a gesture, and that you confirm, right? So I guess it's up to Adele C to precise whether this is what she was asking about, because I thought not.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be in a dictionary, would it? It's not a written word.

Comment: @Actually wiktionary has it, and [mentions the gesture](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yea#Adverb).

Comment: @jlawler Isn't the point of a dictionary to capture *all* words of a language? How can anything not be a written word? (Obviously, apart from illiterate societies and so on.)

Comment: @MarkBeadles Thank you. I only checked Oxford, Cambridge and The Free Dictionary, and didn't think of Wiktionary. Anyway, it still says *often*, not *always*. But now that Adele made the question more precise, I think perhaps this isn't what she had meant.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of any specific movement that would obligatorily accompany a specific word or phrase.

However, especially if you count facial expression as movement, certain rhetoric strategies are, I believe, accompanied at least very often by movement. Sarcasm, mockery and such typically involve a specific intonation and facial expression. In that sense I can see how a certain phrase could begin to usually cooccur with a specific expression through being used primarily in an ironic sense. I suppose that this also accounts to a certain degree for the popularity of emoticons: without them it's often diffucult to decide if what one's reading is a joke or serious.

I suppose *yes* and *no* might often come together with head movement but it's surely not a rule.

On a theoretical ground, I can say this would be a relatively unlikely thing to happen, as being obviously redundant. The only scenario that comes to my mind that could lead to an obligatory cooccurrence, is with 'holy' or taboo words, where e.g. a certain movement could perhaps possibly be required in some culture when mentioning the name of a god, demon or something of the kind.

Answer (score 1):

"Forgive me, father" usually means something different and quite specific when genuflecting and/or crossing oneself.